# Randomization of gRPC server ports

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have a specific problem related to scaling in my code. Let's say I have two services A and B who can communicate with each other using gRPC. Now when load increases on service A I want to horizontally scale but the problem here is I have defined my gRPC port for its server in application.yml file like:

```
server:
  port: 8031
grpc:
  security:
    auth:
      enabled: false
  enabled: true
  port: 6565
```

Now when I try to do this, while one instance of service is running, this gives me an error that port is already bind and cannot start on another port. So is there any way to solve this problem or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done through service discovery.

Comment: I have eureka as discovery but I am not able to find the configuration to do so. Should I specify this in eureka or anything else

Comment: Yes, you need a third party library like: https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/examples.html.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, I just have one query now that if you have any idea regarding load balancing with grpc-starter

Comment: This should enable ribbon loadbalancer: spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=true

Comment: Already done that thanks man

Comment: I have just one question when I try to communicate between service using pods in k8s I get connection timed out. Do you know a work around this? I haven't made GRPC as a different service and used the starter in every service of mine.

Comment: Read The Kubernetes Book by Nigel Poulton's he covers connections between nodes.